# Is there any website which shows tx and deploy fee in fiat price?

Tags: fees

I'd like to estimate how much deploying a contract and sending a transaction costs. It would be nice if there is a website which displays the transaction fee history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain explorers such as https://etherscan.io provide you with all the details of your transactions. Here is an example [page](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeb5480db1b8c3bf4ed55ef1d74fd5025b4d56a0d89b517be81028a8f25a1912a) that shows details about gas and the transaction fee.

Comment: No site for fee chart so far?

Comment: A fee chart does not make much sense since it's not normalized, i.e. each transaction can use different amount of gas. Maybe you are looking for a `gasPrice` chart such as [this](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice) one?